# setting the point color in ListPlot when more than one data set is plotted

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Version 8.04 on windows.

I noticed that when I have 2 data sets and use `ListPlot` on them, that the points shown do not follow the color specified by `PlotStyle` setting for the line color itself when using `Joined->True`.

I just to see if may be I am not understanding the meaning of PlotStyle here.

Here is an example:

```
data1 = {{1, 1}, {2, 1.5}, {3, 2}};
data2 = {{1, 1.5}, {2, 2.5}, {3, 3}};
ListPlot[{data1, data2}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, Joined -> False, 
 Mesh -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Notice that the points have the colors set correctly according to PlotStyle (red then blue).

Now when I add `Joined->True`, see what happens:

```
data1 = {{1, 1}, {2, 1.5}, {3, 2}};
data2 = {{1, 1.5}, {2, 2.5}, {3, 3}};
ListPlot[{data1, data2}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, Joined -> True, 
 Mesh -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Now the *points* on the top line, which is blue have changed color to red, which is the color of the bottom line points!.

Does this make sense?

One way to overcome this is by explicitly adding `PlotMarkers` to give the colors to the points, like this:

```
data1 = {{1, 1}, {2, 1.5}, {3, 2}};
data2 = {{1, 1.5}, {2, 2.5}, {3, 3}};
ListPlot[{data1, data2}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, Joined -> True, 
 Mesh -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {{Graphics[{Red, Point[{0, 0}]}], 
    12}, {Graphics[{Blue, Point[{0, 0}]}], 12}}]
```

[image]

Question: Why the points change color to red in the top line (second plot above) ? and is there a simpler solution to this that what I did above?

**edit(1)**

trying `MeshStyle -> {Red, Blue}` seems to mix things also:

```
data1 = {{1, 1}, {2, 1.5}, {3, 2}};
data2 = {{1, 1.5}, {2, 2.5}, {3, 3}};
ListPlot[{data1, data2}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, Joined -> True, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

[image]

thanks

Comment: Not an answer, but rather an explanation: mesh has a separate style. Try adding `MeshStyle -> Green` to your plot, and see what happens. I do not know of a way to use data series dependent mesh point styling.

Comment: thanks. I tried MeshStyle->{Red,Blue} but that did not help. Please see screen shot in edit(1)

Comment: Correct, that would be useless. All styles are applied, so the last specified color "wins." Unless your plots are extremely complex, `PlotMarkers` is the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's the `Mesh->All` which is messing things up. You can either specify the `MeshStyle` or just leave it off, and set `PlotMarkers->Automatic`.

```
ListPlot[{data1,data2},PlotStyle->{Red,Blue},Joined->True,
 PlotMarkers->Automatic,AxesOrigin->{0,0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thanks. This seems like a good work around. I used `Mesh->All` since it was used in one example in the help as a way to show the points and a line at the same time with `Joined->True`.

Comment: Since version 6 you may use `ListLinePlot` rather than `Joined` or `PlotJoined`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard What is  the difference between `ListLinePlot` and `ListPlot[data,Joined->True`?

Comment: Eli, as far as I recall they are equivalent, but I find `ListLinePlot` cleaner, *unless* I intend to switch back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

To get simply colored points, without changing their shape, and without repeating colors of the lines in the code, you can use `PlotMarkers` like here:

```
ListPlot[{data1, data2}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, Joined -> True, 
 PlotMarkers -> Graphics@{Point[{0, 0}]}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: output of the above command]